# TBS My VTX setting

Tags: team-blacksheep

There is a setting on the full-size CrossFire unit.  What does "My VTX" do?  What really happens when it's on vs off.

Does it affect my VTX if I'm using smart audio vs VTX to the transmitter?

Answer (score 4):

[This blog](https://blog.dronetrest.com/smart-audio-vtx/) describes what the VTX setting is:

> An interesting new feature you will start to see more of is VTX telemetry. **This basically allows you to change settings for your video transmitter via the OSD menu (or your R/C controller if you want to get fancy). These sorts of shortcuts are designed to cut down the setup time allowing you to focus on the fun stuff!**
>
> Does it affect my VTX if I'm using smart audio vs VTX to the transmitter?

The TBS Unify Pro supports smart audio. It doesn't really make a difference but Smart Audio is more modern and SmartAudio protocol coffers commands such as: **GET​ ​SETTINGS, SET​ ​POWER, SET​ ​CHANNEL, SET​ ​FREQUENCY and SET​ ​OPERATION​ ​MODE**